# JPA OneToOne association without foreign key always fail

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I am new to JPA/Hibernate,
I am creating a simple join for getting some data in different table
Let's see like this:

[image]

The purpose is getting the M_PROFILE data based on M_USER.username column, but clearly you see that there is no foreign key in M_PROFILE table.

I just try to use below code but have no results and always got error.

User Entity Class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "M_USER")
public class User {

        @Id
        @Column(name = "id")
        private String uuid;

        @Column(name = "email")
        private String email;

        @Column(name = "username")
        private String username;

        @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        @MapsId("username")
        private Profile profile;

        public String getId() {
            return id;
        }
        public void setId(String id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public String getEmail() {
            return email;
        }
        public void setEmail(String email) {
            this.email = email;
        }

        public String getUsername() {
            return username;
        }
        public void setUsername(String username) {
            this.username = username;
        }

        public Profile getProfile() {
            return profile;
        }
        public void setProfile(Profile profile) {
            this.profile = profile;
        }
    }
```

Profile Entity Class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "M_PROFILE")
public class Profile {

    private String username;
    private String phone;
    private String address;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "username", nullable = false)
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "phone")
    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "address")
    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }
}
```

I got different error when calling

```
User user = userRepository.findByUsername("aswzen");
String phone = user.getProfile().getPhone();
```

for example this one.

> "USER0_"."PROFILE_USERNAME": invalid identifier

Need help, thanks in advance,

NB : i don't have privilege to alter the table..

Comment: I'm not sure but it might be necessary to add the annotations to the getter instead.

Comment: it's surely working.. the code has been running on current environment

Comment: private profile profile; ---> make it capital P

Comment: its typo..mine is already private Profile profile; ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to specify a join column:

```
@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "username", referencedColumnName = "username")
private profile profile;
```

You do not really need the `@MapsId` here.

Comment: not working got error..select user0_.profile as profile1_14_, etc etc from users user0_ where user0_.username=?; Error Msg = ORA-00904: "M_USER0_"."PROFILE": invalid identifier

Answer (score 3):

Don't forget to disable insertable and updatable for JoinColumn

```
@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "username", referencedColumnName = "username", updatable = false, insertable = false)
private profile profile;
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend create third table with relations for your tables

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "M_USER")
public class User {

@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinTable(
name = "user_profile",
joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="user_id"),
inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="profile_username")
 )
private Profile profile;


UPDATE user_profile 
SET user_id = (
    SELECT id
    FROM M_USER
);


UPDATE user_profile 
SET profile_username = (
    SELECT username
    FROM M_USER
);
```

Comment: i don't have access to alter nor create the table.. so the table just as is